# how to import multiple excel sheets into 2 sql server tables?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Am having one excel file with 2 different worksheets as fundmodelrate and project.Now I want to import these 2 different sheet values into 2 different sql tables(k2_fundmodelrate,k2_project).I can able to do import only if am working with 1 sheet and and 1 table,but I want two sheets values to be imported on two tables at the same time on button click event.
My code below:

```
private String strConnection = "Data Source=kuws4;Initial Catalog=jes;User ID=sa;Password=******";               
        protected void btnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            string path = fileuploadExcel.PostedFile.FileName;

            string excelConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\fmr.xls;Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;Persist Security Info=False";

            OleDbConnection excelConnection = new OleDbConnection(excelConnectionString);

            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("Select * from [FundModelRate$]", excelConnection);
            //OleDbCommand cmd1 = new OleDbCommand("Select * from [FundModelRate$],  [Project$]", excelConnection);
            excelConnection.Open();
            OleDbDataReader dReader;
            dReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            SqlBulkCopy sqlBulk = new SqlBulkCopy(strConnection);

            sqlBulk.DestinationTableName = "K2_FundModelRate";
           // sqlBulk.DestinationTableName = "K2_Project";
            sqlBulk.WriteToServer(dReader);
            excelConnection.Close();
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the only way is to loop through your two `sheets`.

Have a look at [This](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8096/C-Retrieve-Excel-Workbook-Sheet-Names) post. This will help you get the `sheet` names.

When you have the `sheet` names, you can then just loop through them and then load them into `SQL`.

Maybe this can help you:

```
OleDbConnection objConn = null;
System.Data.DataTable dt = null;
string excelConnection = "";

if(strFile.Trim().EndsWith(".xlsx"))
{
    excelConnection = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=1\";", strFile);
}
else if(strFile.Trim().EndsWith(".xls")) 
{
    excelConnection = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1\";", strFile);
}

objConn = new OleDbConnection(excelConnection);

objConn.Open();

dt = objConn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);

String[] excelSheets = new String[dt.Rows.Count];
int i = 0;

foreach(DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    excelSheets[i] = row["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
    i++;
}

for(int j=0; j < excelSheets.Length; j++)
{
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("Select * from " + excelSheets[j], excelConnection);

    excelConnection.Open();
    OleDbDataReader dReader;
    dReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    SqlBulkCopy sqlBulk = new SqlBulkCopy(strConnection);

    sqlBulk.DestinationTableName = "YourDestinationTableName";

    sqlBulk.WriteToServer(dReader);
    excelConnection.Close();
}
```

**Note:** Not tested

Answer (score 0):

```
public void importdatafromexcel(string excelfilepath)
        {
            //declare variables - edit these based on your particular situation
            string ssqltable = "test_data";//sql table name
            // make sure your sheet name is correct, here sheet name is sheet1, so you can change your sheet name if havedifferent
            string myexceldataquery = "select * from [Sheet1$]";
            try
            {
                //create our connection strings
                string sexcelconnectionstring = @"provider=microsoft.jet.oledb.4.0;data source=" + excelfilepath + ";extended properties=" + "\"excel 8.0;hdr=yes;\"";
                string ssqlconnectionstring = "server=ServerName;user id=sa;password=sa;database=Databasename;connection reset=false";
                //execute a query to erase any previous data from our destination table
                string sclearsql = "Delete from " + ssqltable;
                SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(ssqlconnectionstring);
                SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand(sclearsql, sqlconn);
                sqlconn.Open();
                sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                sqlconn.Close();
                //series of commands to bulk copy data from the excel file into our sql table
                OleDbConnection oledbconn = new OleDbConnection(sexcelconnectionstring);
                OleDbCommand oledbcmd = new OleDbCommand(myexceldataquery, oledbconn);
                oledbconn.Open();
                OleDbDataReader dr = oledbcmd.ExecuteReader();
                SqlBulkCopy bulkcopy = new SqlBulkCopy(ssqlconnectionstring);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();

                bulkcopy.DestinationTableName = ssqltable;
                bulkcopy.WriteToServer(dr);
                oledbconn.Close();

            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }



/*---------- call that file on buttonclick through OpenDialogBox--------*/

  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DialogResult result = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();

            if (result == DialogResult.OK) // Test result.
            {
                string strfilename = openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory + openFileDialog1.FileName;
                importdatafromexcel(strfilename);

            }

            Console.WriteLine(result);
            MessageBox.Show("Exported to SQL successfully");
        }
```